# Auto deploy after commiting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, hexo

I'm developing on Ruby on Rails and write some articles on Hexo.

My project source code repo is on Gitlab server.

So my deploy flow is

1. Commit the production code to Gitlab from my working space.
2. Login in the Web server, then pull the production code from Gitlab
3. Restart the Webserver, or regenerate articles for Hexo.

Is there any way to let me, renew the webserver with one step ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hexo is on node so not sure how ruby on rails fits in. I would recommend you take a look at their documentation which has few plugins for deployments [link](http://hexo.io/docs/deployment.html)

pasting an excerpt that's valid at this moment

Edit `_config.yml`.

```
deploy:
  type: git
  message: [message]
  repo:
   gitlab: <repository url>,[branch]
   gitcafe: <repository url>,[branch]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to setup a GitLab [hook](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/web_hooks/web_hooks.html) which should call a `hexo generate` command.